# How to deploy in Google app engine using admin api for Java Project

Tags: java, google-app-engine, deployment, google-cloud-platform

Does any one used google app engine admin api to deploy the new version for java project?
It is working fine as shown in the example for python project.
But for java project there is no proper guidance or examples.

Please share the request body json if any one has one.
consider you have placed the war file in gcs.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.services.versions/create

Comment: Please edit your headline. This place is inappropiate for keywords.

Comment: Some times it is coming ,Version deployed, but there was an error connecting Cloud Endpoints when deploying through admin api

Answer (score -1):

See [Deploying a Java App](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp#using_appcfg_alternative).

You may need to convert all of your XML configuration files to YAML files.  The "appcfg" utility installs with the App Engine SDK and is probably already on your machine (search for "appcfg.cmd").  This utility will prepare your app properly for upload, including automatically converting your XMLs to YAMLs.

If you don't really need to use the API you can always use "appcfg" followed by a [gcloud app deploy](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy) command.  The [gcloud utility](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/) is fairly straightforward and tends to get updates quickly.

Comment: Gcloud Sdk is for compute engine.It will be accessed from terminal.

Comment: I need to deploy from java using admin api.

Comment: In other words I need to Programatically manage the java app. python application is working fine. but the documentation is not clear for java application.if any one knows for java application please share the link or some referrences.

Comment: The "gcloud" utility isn't just for Compute Engine.  And hey guess what that utility uses behind the scenes?  Yep, the Admin API.  So this is why my answer is a good hint... step 1 would be get your project to deploy with gcloud.  Look at the setup that appcfg does.  Step 2, try uploading the post-appcfg deployment with your own code using the Admin API.  And yes this means you may indeed have to just use YAML files or run appcfg every time.

Comment: Thanks Roberts.I am already using gcloud utility and appcfg to deploy the application.My point is  i want to do it programmatically using admin api and keep the source (war) in gcs.I am not able to convert appengine-web.xml to yaml file.please let me know if you have any samples.convert yaml to app.json converter.oy utility is available in google.

Comment: Aha yes you should probably clarify your question... I was assuming code was on your local machine.  For java there used to be a feature called "Push to Deploy" which leveraged Jenkins.  It was taken away... I didn't use it so I'm not sure what the reasoning was. I don't see a replacement.  If you figure this out please answer your own question.  I do see that containers have a "continuous deployment" option: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/continuous-delivery